# Why use a intermediate variable to return an arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

On Educative.io I have an exercise whose solution uses an intermediate variable and I don't understand why I can't do it directly.

*Exercise: Given an array of arrays, each of which contains a set of numbers, write a function that returns an array where each item is the sum of all the items in the sub-array. For example,*

```
var numbers = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7], 
  [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
];

arraySum(numbers);
```

*Would return the following array:*

`[10, 18, 42]`

My solution:

```
  var sums = [];
  for(i=0; i<numbers.lenght; i++){
    for(j=0; j<numbers[i].lenght; j++){
      sums[i]= sums[i] + numbers[i][j] ;
    }
  }
  return sums;
}
```

The correct reply is:

```
var arraySum = function(numbers) {
  var sums = [];
  var sum = 0;
  var count = 0;
   for (i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++){
      for (j = 0; j< numbers[i].length;j++){
      sum = sum + numbers[i][j]}
      sums[i] = sum;
      sum = 0;
  } 
  return sums;
}
```

Why using the variable **sum** to write in the array **sums** ?

Comment: If you fix the typo, your code results in `[ NaN, NaN, NaN ]`, because you add a `number` to `undefined` initially. Their `sum` variable is just one way of overcoming this problem. For your's this would work: `sums[i] = (sums[i] || 0) + numbers[i][j];`

Answer (score 1):

> Why using the variable sum to write in the array sums ?

It's **slightly** more efficient, in theory, to use that local variable in the inner loop rather than going back to the array every time for the current value. It's unlikely to make a difference in real-world code, though. Also, if they're going to do that, they might want to do it with `numbers[i]` as well.

But note that your solution has a typo: `lenght` instead of `length`. If your solution was rejected, it may be down to that rather than the `sum` thing. Also, you need `sum[i] = 0;` at the top of the body of the inner loop, since otherwise you're using `sum[i]` when it doesn't have a value (so you'll get `undefined`, which means the addition will result in `NaN`).

---

But I'm sorry to see that that "correct" answer has code relying on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (it never declares `i`). Also that it uses inconsistent bracing style (and that awful `}`-at-the-end-of-the-line in one place, which I'd strongly urge you not to adopt). It also never uses `count` for anything. If that's really the "right answer" they give, you might consider a different tutorial or course.

Comment: I fix the typo 'lenght' and the output is 'NaN,NaN,NaN' .

Comment: @cibirsk - I don't have any specific one I would recommend. (The NaN is because of the issue with initializing `sum[i]`, I edited the answer a few minutes before your comment, you may have been seeing the older copy.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouls suggest a slightly different approach by

- declaring **all** variables, as well the ones for the loop,
- removing unnecessary/unused variables,
- initialize a value at an index outside of the most inner loop,
- update the value at index with the value.

```js
var arraySum = function(numbers) {
        const sums = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sums[i] = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                sums[i] += numbers[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sums;
    };

console.log(arraySum([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]));
```